# Connectionstring not a member of my.mysettings

Tags: vb.net, dataset

I had my vb.net app working properly up until now. To make it compatible with 64bit applications, i changed targetCPU to x64 and that was when all issues started arising. Now i see "daveconnectionstring is not a member of dataenrolment.my.mysettings". The actual module that gives off this error is

```
    <Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute(),  _
     Global.System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Data.Design.TypedDataSetGenerator", "4.0.0.0")>  _
    Private Sub InitConnection()
        Me._connection = New Global.System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection()
        Me._connection.ConnectionString = Global.DataEnrollment.My.MySettings.Default.daveConnectionString
    End Sub
```

what have i done wrong pls.

Comment: Are you specifically making your application a full 64 bit application, or do you simply want it to be able to run on 64 bit operating systems.  If it's simply the latter then there is no need to change the target cpu.

Comment: No. I actually want it to run on both 64 and 32bit windows machines. After changing back to X86, the errors would not still go away.

Comment: Did you by any chance take a full backup of the solution prior to changing the cpu target?

Comment: From the build menu I would try 'Clean Solution'.  Then I would 'Save all' and close the solution.  Reopen the solution and then try 'Rebuild Solution' from the build menu.  I can't guarantee that it will work but it might so long as you did not radically alter any code after you noticed the errors that prompted your post.